# InputBinding instead of PreviewKeyDown

Tags: wpf, command, icommand, inputbinding

In the MainView of my Code, i had this event to catch keyDown:

```
#region Constructor
PreviewKeyDown += SoftKeyMainPreviewKeyDown;
#endregion

private void SoftKeyMainPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up:
                DoSomething();
                break;
            .....
        }
}
```

Now I want to move that into InputBindings in the XAML.

My First try:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Up" Command="{Binding ElementName=_MaschinenView, Path=UpCommand}" />
    ....
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public ICommand UpCommand { get; set; }

UpCommand = new SimpleCommand { ExecuteDelegate = delegate { MoveFocusInDirection(Keyboard.FocusedElement, new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up)); } };
```

With this nothing happens. Most probably the KeyDown-Event is handled by an Child-Element.

Is it posible to set previewkeydown in XAML in InputBindings? And how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Key property instead of Gesture? Like this:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="{Binding ElementName=_MaschinenView, Path=UpCommand}" />
    ....
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```